# Receive files securely over the Internet

Tags: email, encryption, file-transfer, attachments

Presently, I receive e-mail attachments from many different senders. Due to the contents of the file attachments, I want them to be protected (i.e. encrypted) while in transit to me.

How can the senders send these files to me securely?  Is there a simple solution that would work for senders without much technical know-how? It's OK if they're sent via a method *other* than e-mail too.

**Edit:**

The files contain payroll data, so they should only be readable by the sender and myself while in transit.  Once I receive the files, they'll be stored on my secured system and will no longer need protection.

Comment: Most archives support encryption if the one you use does not use ine that does or better yet don't send files over email use a cloud storage and upload the encrypted files and download the encrypted file

Comment: @Ramhound Duly noted on *don't send files over email* hence the very reason for my question. I don't have control over the sender's computers, so it's a gamble what archive software the sender might have.

Comment: You can always NOT send PII over email; there are better ways to share PII diles

Comment: There are services designed to do this for you, but [su] does not allow spam so I won't name them.

Comment: @Twisty, do some research on secure file transfer services using Google. There are several out there, and for a single-user recipient they shouldn't cost too much.

Comment: Zip it with a password.

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that GPG is too complex for an end-user with limited technical experience to set up, I would recommend both you and counterpart install a program like 7zip (http://www.7-zip.org/) which permits you to compress and encrypt files that can then be sent by email. 7zip, on Windows, also integrates with the file explorer, so you can right-click on the .7z file that you receive and unencrypt/decompress it immediately.

The only procedural prerequisite is that you'll need to share an encryption password with your counterpart; usually by phone or some other means. (Although, to be honest, I and many of those I work with just send the password in a separate email that doesn't indicate the email contains a password.)

Answer (score 1):

Like physical locks, with encryption the first two questions you need to answer are: Who are you protecting it from ? and, for how long ? It'll greatly affect the scope of answers given.

For non tech savvy users you're probably looking at something like AES encoded zip files with a known (decent) password.

GPG would be a lot better though *if* they've got the know-how, which they probably won't.